# After pre-processing my data in pandas, how can I drop unneeded dataframes prior to loading in Power Bi?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, powerbi

As part of my pre-processing, I build several dataframes with pandas. But all I need for the final load into Power Bi is the final dataframe. How do I delete the unneeded dataframes in the final step of my python script? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### `del` statement does not delete an instance, it merely deletes a name.

When you do `del i`, you are deleting just the name *i* - but the instance is still bound to some other name, so it won't be Garbage-Collected.

If you want to release memory, your dataframes has to be **Garbage-Collected**, i.e. delete all references to them.

If you created your dateframes dynamically to list, then removing that list will trigger Garbage Collection.

```
>>> lst = [pd.DataFrame(), pd.DataFrame(), pd.DataFrame()]
>>> del lst     # memory is released
```

### If you created some variables, you have to delete them all.

```
>>> a, b, c = pd.DataFrame(), pd.DataFrame(), pd.DataFrame()
>>> lst = [a, b, c]
>>> del a, b, c # dfs still in list
>>> del lst     # memory release now
```